# Quadratic extension and prime ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory

Let $B/A$ be a quadratic Galois extension between local domains. Define ${\mathrm{Gal}}(B/A) = \{e,\sigma\}$.

Choose two prime ideals ${\frak P}_1, {\frak P}_2$ of $B$ such that ${\frak P}_2 = {\frak P}_1^{\sigma}$, i.e. both are Galois-conjugates.

Define ${\frak p} = {\frak P}_1 \cap A = {\frak P}_2 \cap A$, which is the unique prime ideal of $A$ lying below ${\frak P}_1$ and ${\frak P}_2$. Suppose that ${\frak p}$ is a height-one prime ideal of $A$ and ${\frak p} = (a_1)$, i.e. principal.

Suppose that for a finitely-generated ideal ${\cal I}$ of $B$, the radical $\sqrt{\cal I}$ is always a finitely-generated ideal.

Then, I would like to ask

### Q. If the radical $\sqrt{{\frak p}B} = {\frak P}_1 \cap {\frak P}_2$ satisfies that, for $n < \infty$, $\sqrt{{\frak p}B} = (a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, i.e., finitely generated, then are both ${\frak P}_1$ and ${\frak P}_2$ also finitely generated in B?

Answer (score -2):

I found that one may use the equality

\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{IJ} = \sqrt{I \cap J} \cdots (\dagger).
\end{equation*}

Applying ${\dagger}$ to ${\frak P}_1$ and ${\frak P_2}$ in the question and being helped by the assumption, we obtain the following equality$\colon$
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{{\frak P}_1{\frak P}_2} = (a_1,\ldots,a_n).
\end{equation*}
Thus we obtain for $m < \infty$
\begin{equation*}
{\frak P}_1{\frak P}_2 = (b_1,\ldots,b_m) \cdots (\sharp).
\end{equation*}
This is the property enjoyed by the ring $B$. (I am sorry not to have mentioned this crucial property of $B$).

Then, because ${\frak P}_1$ and ${\frak P}_2$ are Galois conjugates with each other, if we suppose ${\frak P}_1 = (g_1,g_2,...,g_m,\ldots)$ and ${\frak P}_2 = (\sigma(g_1),\sigma(g_2),\ldots,,\sigma(g_m),\ldots)$, then we shall have the equality

\begin{equation*}
{\frak P}_1{\frak P}_2 = (g_1\sigma(g_1),g_1\sigma(g_2),\ldots,g_i\sigma(g_j),\ldots|i,j \geq 1) \cdots (\flat).
\end{equation*}

Now by comparing $(\sharp)$ and $(\flat)$, we can deduce the contradiction. I am a bit awkward at this last step.

So, supposing the equality $(\sharp)$ and $(\flat)$, how can one deduce a contradiction? Most likely, one needs to consider $A$ and ${\frak p}$ as well, focusing attention to the relative situation.